# Am I safe (XSS injection, etc) with my website contact form with Google Captcha?

Tags: security, web

I have suffered injection in my website (from a search box in a KB system). I removed that KB system but have a Contact Form (with Google Captcha) where the user enters his name, email and message and I use PHP mail() to send me the message.

Is it possible that an attacker can get access to my website from a possible attack to that form? Or the worst scenario could just be that he uses it to send Spam?

This is my PHP code before calling "main()":

```
<?php

$fname = $_POST['contact-f-name'];
$lname = $_POST['contact-l-name'];
$email = $_POST['contact-email'];
$text = $_POST['contact-message'];

$companyname = $_POST['company-name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$address = "myemail@myemail.com"; 

$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($email) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($email) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/plain; Charset=UTF-8 \r\n";

$message =          ."Name: ".strip_tags($fname)." ".strip_tags($lname)."\r\n"
                    ."Email: ".strip_tags($email)."\r\n"
                    ."Company Name: ".strip_tags($companyname)."\r\n"
                    ."Subject: ".strip_tags($subject)."\r\n"
                    ."Message: ".strip_tags($text)."\r\n";

if(@mail($address, $subject, $message, $headers)) { echo "true"; } 
else { echo "false"; }
exit;
?>
```

Comment: as with all web forms that accept user input, the input must be sanitized to prevent  injection attacks such as XSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR: Short answer: Maybe:

While I do not have the time right now to do a complete and exacting answer to this post; I will point you to some best practises, and lots of links to other more verbose answers to similar questions regarding making user inputted data *safe*.

## How to make the inputs safer?

- [Disable certain dangerous PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1865020/3536236). Read the second answeer rathr than the "ticked" answer.
- Use PHPs [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to force input the their correct types, especially for emails:

  ```
   $email = filter_var($_POST['contact-email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  ```
- use `preg_replace()` (or `str_replace()` ) to remove unwanted characters from your values. This can most typically be backticks, quotes of any kind, forward slashes or backslashes. [*Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242581/php-is-it-safe-to-include-a-file-based-on-a-get-variable-if-you-use-preg-repla).
- I recommend replacing `mail()` in your code with [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).
- `strip_tags` is ok, but just ok. It has flaws (such as dealing with unclosed tags). be aware of that.
- Your PHP should be suitably jailed so *if* someone can run `exec(...)` commands (*Ohsh1tOhsh1tOhsh1t*) you have not (literally) lost your server.

## What else can I read?

- [This huge topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication?rq=1) on how to deal with forms on PHP
- [This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42498/which-is-the-best-way-to-sanitize-user-input-in-php) about how to "sanitise" user input.
- [OWASP PHP filters](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_PHP_Filters) for cleaning inputs.
- [Disable dangerous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865020/php-how-to-disable-dangerous-functions)
- PHP `fitler_var` [sanitisation filter list](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)
- [Securing user variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538353/php-secure-user-variable) (database related mostly)
- [Further wise words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3126175/3536236) on data sanitisation.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I'll go into each topic that you've mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this post answers your query. If it does please tick the tick, thanks `:-)`